# HTML::FormHandler dynamic form with HTML::FormHandler::Widget::Theme::Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, catalyst

I'm using [`HTML::FormHandler`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::FormHandler) and creating a dynamic form, and I'd like to be able to use [`HTML::FormHandler::Widget::Theme::Bootstrap`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::FormHandler::Widget::Theme::Bootstrap) with it.

However, I can't figure out how to get a dynamic form to include 'withs'. The documentation shows that you create a dynamic form like so:

```
my $form = HTML::FormHandler->new(
name => 'user_form',
item => $user,
field_list => [
    'username' => {
        type  => 'Text',
        apply => [ { check => qr/^[0-9a-z]*\z/,
           message => 'Contains invalid characters' } ],
    },
    'select_bar' => {
        type     => 'Select',
        options  => \@select_options,
        multiple => 1,
        size     => 4,
    },
],
);
```

Does anyone know how I could get this form to use `HTML::FormHandler::Widget::Theme::Bootstrap`?

Answer (score 0):

Since [HTML::FormHandler::Widget::Theme::Bootstrap](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aFormHandler%3a%3aWidget%3a%3aTheme%3a%3aBootstrap) is really just a [Moose::Role](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aRole), you should be able to apply it to an instance of your form like so:

```
use HTML::FormHandler::Widget::Theme::Bootstrap;
HTML::FormHandler::Widget::Theme::Bootstrap->meta->apply($form);
```

it is Moose at the end of the day.